# How to make asynchronous call ajax in Marionette Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, marionette

In my front app javascript, I send data into the back with this call ajax, when a button is clicked :

```
submit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('form').serializeArray().reduce(function(a, x) { a[x.name] = x.value; return a; }, {}); // mettre sous format json compréhensible
    var coords = this.map.drawLayer
    if (typeof(coords) == 'undefined') {
        console.log('dessinez qqch')
    }
    else {
        console.log('le traitement commence');
        formData['coords'] = coords.getLatLngs();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/api/getFormData',
            data: JSON.stringify(formData) ,
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })};
    },
```

This code is in searchView.js

I have an other call ajax in leafletView.js which collects data from the back after treatment, with this call ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://127.0.0.1/api/ndviAuto',
    success: function(data){
        console.log("les données ont été récupérées");
        // console.log(data);
        _this.mymap.setView([data[0]['coords_center']['lat'], data[0]['coords_center']['lng']], 12);
        var mapDataLayer = L.geoJson(data,{
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return  L.polygon(latlng);
            }}).addTo(_this.mymap);
    }
});
```

I want this call ajax to be executed only if the first one is executed, I know I have to use $.Deferred(), but I don't quite understand how it works.

The leafletView is created in the searchView like this :

```
onShow: function(options) {
    this.map = new LeafletView();
    this.testCarte.show(this.map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In leafletView.js

```
setActionAllowed: function(allowed){
    this.actionAllowed = allowed;
}

if(this.actionAllowed){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://127.0.0.1/api/ndviAuto',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("les données ont été récupérées");
            // console.log(data);
            _this.mymap.setView([data[0]['coords_center']['lat'], data[0]['coords_center']['lng']], 12);
            var mapDataLayer = L.geoJson(data,{
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    return  L.polygon(latlng);
            }}).addTo(_this.mymap);
         }
    });
}
```

In searchView.js

```
submit: function(e){
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('form').serializeArray().reduce(function(a, x) { a[x.name] = x.value; return a; }, {}); // mettre sous format json compréhensible
    var coords = this.map.drawLayer
    if (typeof(coords) == 'undefined') {
        console.log('dessinez qqch')
    }
    else {
        console.log('le traitement commence');
        formData['coords'] = coords.getLatLngs();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/api/getFormData',
            data: JSON.stringify(formData) ,
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
                console.log(response);
                //sets allowed value
                self.map.setActionAllowed(true);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                //sets allowed value
                self.map.setActionAllowed(false);
            }
    })};
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways to achieve what you want. If your two views have some sort of connection, e.g. parent/child or siblings connection, you can define method in one view and reference it in the other view. Something like:

```
// parent/child
const parent = marionette.View.extend({
  // ...
  doSth1() {
    $.ajax({
      // ...
    });
  },

  onRender() {
    this.getRegion('whatever').show(new child({doSth1: this.doSth1.bind(this)}));
  }
});

const child = marionette.View.extend({
  doSth2() {
    const self = this;
    $.ajax({
      // ...
      success() {
        this.options.doSth1();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Follow the same pattern, you could implement it for other conneciton like siblings, or parent/child but with reverse control flow e.g. parent call method of children. Although this approach will do the job, I think it's only ok if you apply it for one-level parent/child which have child call function of parent. The reason is that code could become un-maintainable easily if apply for other cases.

Another the way is to use Backbone Events, or Backbone Radio. These are my preferable ways in this case. Example using Backbone Radio:

```
const Radio = require('backbone.radio');

const ajaxChannel = Radio.channel('ajax');

const view1 = marionette.View.extend({
  initialize() {
    this.listenTo(ajaxChannel, 'getSth', () => {
      $.ajax({
        // ...
      })
    });
  }
});

const view2 = marionette.View.extend({
  postSth() {
    $.ajax({
      // ...
      success() {
        ajaxChannel.trigger('getSth')
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can export a state in searchView.js and import in leafletView.js,like this

searchView.js

```
state = false
success:function(){
  state = true
}
export state
```

leafletView.js

```
import {state} from 'searchView.js'
if(state){
  $.ajax(...)
}
```

Comment: it's not working, there is an error of syntax, import isn't recognized. this syntax doesn't look like javascript ...